# android navigation popBackStack behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have code below that adds random fragments(First,SecondFragment or ThirdFragment)

```
private fun addFragment() {
        activeFragment = if (activeFragment is FirstFragment) {
            SecondFragment()
        } else if (activeFragment is SecondFragment) {
            ThirdFragment()
        } else {
            FirstFragment()
        }
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.fragment_container, activeFragment!!)
            ?.addToBackStack(null)
            ?.commit()

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val fragment = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
        if (fragment != null) {
            Log.d("mytag", "onBackPressed: $fragment")
            fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
            return
        }
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

In the code above everything works fine. I mean when i press back button it pops the last fragment and shows previous if there any.

But if i remove `return statement` inside if check (in `onBackPressed function`), then it pops 2 fragments at once from back stack.(I added `onBackStackChangedListener` and i can see how many items are left when i pop, so if there are 3 fragments i back stack when i pop it removes 2 fragments and only 1 remains, and then if i click back again, it removes last fragment and also destroys the app)

Comment: Why are you overriding `onBackPressed()` at all? Fragments already take care of handling the back button when you use `addToBackStack()`.

Comment: hmm i did not know this, i think i watched old tutorial in which instructor said you need to override to handle back behaviour for fragments, anyway, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because Fragments *already* handle the system back button when you use `addToBackStack()` as part of the `super.onBackPressed()` call.

That means you don't need to override `onBackPressed()` at all when using fragments.